# Nested CheckBoxList using DataSet and Repeaters

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I'm trying to wire up some CBL's using a repeater and dataset. The dataset contains 2 tables with the same schema and a (one, single) relation (in SQL land think of it as a self join).

When the control is rendered if I set my DataSource = the relationship, I am able to get the children elements to show; so I know the model is good, although misplaced (on purpose to test the model - see code below).

The problem is:

1. I am having difficulty getting the parent elements to show up at all
2. Not all parents have children, and the ones that don't still need to show up
3. Am I approaching this in the right frame of mind? i.e. Am I missing something fundamental? Implementation outside of CBL(plain text) works fine [per this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306154)

   ```
   <asp:Repeater ID="ParentRepeater" runat="server">
         <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:CheckBoxList ID="ParentCBL" runat="server"
                DataSource='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Joined") %>'
                DataTextField="TextProperty" 
                DataValueField="ValueProperty">
              </asp:CheckBoxList>
              <asp:Repeater ID="ChildRepeater" runat="server">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:CheckBoxList ID="ChildCBL" runat="server"
                       DataSource='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Joined") %>'
                       DataTextField="TextProperty" 
                       DataValueField="ValueProperty">
                     </asp:CheckBoxList>
                  </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:Repeater>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
   ```

Page Load is nothing spectacular

```
DataSet ds = Foo.foo();
ParentRepeater.DataSource = ds.Tables["Parent"];
ParentRepeater.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In your code you don't bind **ChildRepeater**
2. If you want just change plain text to Checkbox in according to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306154
   then you don't need to use CheckBoxList. But you should only use single checkbox inside repeater.

Comment: So should a different control be used to show the relationships? If so what do you recommend a treeview?

Comment: Depends on your requirements. If you want just to see checkboxes for each node then TreeView will be fine solution as it allows you to use checkboxes in nodes. But repeaters is also possible despite of that you use it wrong.

Comment: @Alexy right on the money. Stayed with the repeater and added a hiddenfield containing the value of the checkboxes (initial reasoning for going with a CBL).